# На какие вопросы вы отвечаете?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Как вы выбираете, на какой вопрос отвечать, а какой пропустить?

Что важно в первую очередь?

Всегда ли качество вопроса связано с желанием на него ответить? А как именно связано?

Влияет ли наличие ответов? Принятого ответа? Активного обсуждения в комментариях?

Ну и всё в этом духе :)

Comment: По крайней мере один человек (закрывашка?) жутко испугался.

Comment: @avp, +4 -4, один (не я) добавил в избранное и 1 голос за закрытие - полный комплект собрал... кроме ответов :D

Comment: @Qwertiy осталось поймать тревогу "оскорбительное". ))

Comment: если есть что сказать - оставляю комментарий, если автор не понял и/или у меня есть достаточно времени и желания дать нормальный ответ - отвечаю. Если жалко тратить время даже на коммент - пропускаю вопрос мимо

Comment: "Всегда ли качество вопроса свя..." - Всегда.

Answer (score 19):

> Как вы выбираете, на какой вопрос отвечать, а какой пропустить?

В основном, ищу интересные для себя вопросы.

- Это могут быть проблемы, с которыми я сталкивался и уже искал способ их решения.
- Это могут быть проблемы, с которыми я гипотетически могу столкнуться в работе, поэтому полезно решить их заранее.
- Это может быть просто интересная мне в данную секунду задача.

Что угодно.

Ну и, конечно, я не пропускаю простые вопросы. Порой, вопрошающие не знают, как сформулировать свою мысль, чтобы составить поисковый запрос. Если я понимаю, что смогу найти информацию по вопросу, я на него отвечу. Соревновательный момент никто не отменял.

> Что важно в первую очередь?

Главное, чтобы вопрос был хоть немного мне интересен.

> Всегда ли качество вопроса связано с желанием на него ответить? А как именно связано?

Нет, не всегда. Зависит от степени моей заинтересованности и любопытства.

- Если вопрос мне интересен, то я постараюсь на него ответить. Даже если вопрос плохо оформлен, я улучшу его с помощью правки, если было недостаточно информации от вопрошающего — я постараюсь уточнить необходимые детали.
- Если вопрос мне не особо интересен, то я ограничусь только правкой.

> Влияет ли наличие ответов? Принятого ответа? Активного обсуждения в комментариях?

Из всего вышеперечисленного в некоторой степени влияет наличие ответа.
Если кто-то сформулировал достаточный в моем понимании ответ или я не могу предложить альтернативный вариант, то, конечно, я не буду отвечать. Максимум оставлю комментарий, если что-то было упущено.
Остальное неважно.

Добавлю от себя, что интерес к вопросу могут повысить следующие факторы:

- Мне понятен вопрос
- Могу воспроизвести проблему, если это того требуется
- Я сталкивался с этой проблемой и знаю на него ответ

---

Отдельно стоит отметить лень.

Иногда я не отвечаю на тривиальные вопросы, поскольку мне не хочется тратить время на цитирование одной-двух строк документации, или когда решение может быть найдено путем копирования текста ошибки в поисковик.
Иногда я пропускаю интересные вопросы, если понимаю, что собирать информацию для ответа буду долго. Причина та же: лень.

Answer (score 8):

1. Тематика (язык, библиотека). Почти не заглядываю в вопросы по языкам, и технологиям, которых я точно не знаю. Хотя можно иногда заглянуть, если формулировка интересная и обещает познавательное обсуждение.

   - Хотя можно заглянуть, чтобы поучиться чему-нибудь.
   - Если вопросов по интересным тематикам нет, можно заглянуть и к соседям, конечно.
2. Заголовок вопроса! Он очень важен. Если это просто дамп сообщения об ошибке, ещё и с номером строки и именем файла, желание читать дальше отпадает. Если автор не нашёл времени сформулировать вопрос хорошо, не хочется тратить своё время тоже.
3. Личность автора. Отвечать на вопросы троллей — себе дороже, нет, спасибо. Если автор, наоборот, хороший участник сайта, хочется ответить ему получше.
4. Текст вопроса.

   - Если в нём длиннющая простыня кода, первый абзац должен быть *очень* хорош, чтобы была мотивация читать дальше.
   - Если автор грамотно формулирует мысли, на его вопрос хочется дать ответ.
   - Если код или текст плохо отформатирован, или содержит грамматические ошибки, отношение к автору соответствующее. Хотя конечно оно не должно меняться из-за грамматики.
5. Смысл вопроса. Вопросы «как сделать правильно/хорошо» интереснее вопросов «как сделать». Вопросы «как сделать» интереснее вопросов «отладьте мой код». Вопросы о том, почему устроен язык так, а не иначе, практически всегда интересны. Вопросы о тонкостях языков всегда интересны. Вопросы, в которых анонсируется баг компилятора, и в которых **действительно** найден баг компилятора (их меньше одного на тысячу), великолепны.
6. Субъективная полезность вопроса. Если вопрос выглядит как домашнее задание, скорее всего, это домашнее задание и есть, [что бы не говорилось о шансах насчёт его полезности](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8). Домашнее задание должно быть *очень* интересным, чтобы остановиться на нём.
7. Ответы. Если есть хорошие ответы, стоит поставить им плюс, и свалить отвечать на другие вопросы. И вопросу тоже плюс, раз он сгенерировал хороший ответ. Впрочем, если к ответу можно что-то добавить, почему бы и не добавить.
8. Комментарии. Комментарии к вопросу скорее интересны тем, кто пришёл за ответом. Хорошо сформулированный вопрос в комментариях не нуждается. Хотя вполне может быть глубокомысленный комментарий, содержащий в себе пол-ответа и ещё море дзена, почему бы не почитать?

Answer (score 7):

1. Заголовок должен быть нормальным. Т.е. не что-то типа "программа не работает"
2. Не должно быть простыней текста.
3. Должно быть отоформатированное сообщение об ошибке. И номер строки её появления. И сама эта строка.
4. Вопрос должен быть понятен. Т.е. ТС должен уметь сформулировать свою мысль.
5. Если есть нормальный ответ (даже не принятый) - отвечать смысла особого нет.